# Using Mule - Datawave want to download all Images in HTML

Tags: mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I have a situation, where I need to download all images added (URL) in HTML, using Datawave.

Example : Here is my HTML received in payload

```
<div class="Container"> \n\n
<img src="https://test.documentforce.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka0000000id01&amp;feoid=00aF000002MA1&amp;refid=0BR5w000001mnlq" alt="">
<div>...</div>\n\n
<img src="https://test.documentforce.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka0000000id02&amp;feoid=00aF000002GE2&amp;refid=0BR5w000001hh2u" alt="">\n\n
</div>
```

Can you give me some sample code which go through the HTML and download all actual images instead of URL's

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show how you've attempted to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use readUrl with content-type as application/octet-stream, though it would give you a stream of bytes. What you can do is extract the content of the url and then do a file read, something akin to what's been described [here](https://medium.com/@deb0/mule4-download-a-file-as-an-attachment-using-http-connector-95e22997571a)